# Failed Installation D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphics, installation

I need **D3.js** for a Javascript program, but I get a problem installing:

I entered in Terminal (I'm using MacOS):

```
npm install d3
```

But get an error message:

> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cliang/package.json'
>   npm WARN cliang No description
>   npm WARN cliang No repository field.
>   npm WARN cliang No README data
>   npm WARN cliang No license field.

I had an HTML file, but couldn't display its contents.

What went wrong in the installation, and what can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

So first things first, you do have a `package.json` file in the application directory right?

have you run just regular old `npm install` to check that you aren't missing a dependency in the project?

It could also be related to NPM v3's changed installation behaviour.

I've had some success resolving these issues by doing the following:

1. Ensure dependencies described correctly on package.json
2. Just type npm install and hit Enter.
3. Check issue still exists. and If issue not resolved, continue these methods.
4. type npm cache clean and hit Enter
5. type sudo npm install -g npm and hit Enter.
6. Retry npm install and hit Enter.